# Accessing final variables from another class and correctly outputting the results

Tags: java, android

I have two class files set up for an android RSS reader.

Instead of having getters for the information in `public static class FeedResponse` and `public static class ItemResponse` which are in `GetNetworkRequest` below. I have used public final string variables.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the information from those final variables and set them to `feeds` and `items` in `DataSource` effectively replacing my `createFakeData` method.

I have verified that all information from the network request does get loaded into `FeedReponse` and `ItemResponse` lists.

How do I go about accessing those lists and setting them in `DataSource`?

**DataSource**

```
package io.bloc.android.blocly.api;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.bloc.android.blocly.BloclyApplication;
import io.bloc.android.blocly.R;
import io.bloc.android.blocly.api.model.RssFeed;
import io.bloc.android.blocly.api.model.RssItem;
import io.bloc.android.blocly.api.network.GetFeedsNetworkRequest;
import io.bloc.android.blocly.api.network.NetworkRequest;

import static io.bloc.android.blocly.api.network.GetFeedsNetworkRequest.*;

public class DataSource extends GetFeedsNetworkRequest {

    public List<RssFeed> feeds;
    public List<RssItem> items;

    public DataSource() {
        feeds = new ArrayList<RssFeed>();
        items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();

        createFakeData();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GetFeedsNetworkRequest("http://feeds.feedburner.com/androidcentral?format=xml").performRequest();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public List<RssFeed> getFeeds() {
        return feeds;
    }

    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    void createFakeData(){

        feeds.add(new RssFeed("My Favorite Feed!",
                "This feed is just incredible, I can't even begin to tell you…",
                "http://favoritefeed.net", "http://feeds.feedburner.com/favorite_feed?format=xml"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            items.add(new RssItem(String.valueOf(i),
                    BloclyApplication.getSharedInstance().getString(R.string.placeholder_headline) + " " + i,
                    BloclyApplication.getSharedInstance().getString(R.string.placeholder_content),
                    "http://favoritefeed.net?story_id=an-incredible-news-story",
                    "http://rs1img.memecdn.com/silly-dog_o_511213.jpg",
                    0, System.currentTimeMillis(), false, false));
        }
    }
}
```

**GetNetworkRequest**

```
package io.bloc.android.blocly.api.network;

import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.util.Log;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;


public class GetFeedsNetworkRequest extends NetworkRequest<List<GetFeedsNetworkRequest.FeedResponse>> {

    public static final int ERROR_PARSING = 3;

    private static final String XML_TAG_TILE = "title";
    private static final String XML_TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String XML_TAG_LINK = "link";
    private static final String XML_TAG_ITEM = "item";
    private static final String XML_TAG_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
    private static final String XML_TAG_GUID = "guid";
    private static final String XML_TAG_ENCLOSURE = "enclosure";
    private static final String XML_ATTRIBUTE_URL = "url";
    private static final String XML_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = "type";


    String [] feedUrls;

    public GetFeedsNetworkRequest(String... feedUrls) {
        this.feedUrls = feedUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedResponse> performRequest(){
        List<FeedResponse> responseFeeds = new ArrayList<FeedResponse>(feedUrls.length);
        for (String feedUrlString : feedUrls) {
            InputStream inputStream = openStream(feedUrlString);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return  null;
            }
            try {
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);

                String channelTitle = optFirstTagDocument(xmlDocument, XML_TAG_TILE);
                String channelDescription = optFirstTagDocument(xmlDocument, XML_TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                String channelURL = optFirstTagDocument(xmlDocument, XML_TAG_LINK);

                NodeList allItemNodes = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName(XML_TAG_ITEM);
                List<ItemResponse> responseItems = new ArrayList<ItemResponse>(allItemNodes.getLength());
                for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < allItemNodes.getLength(); itemIndex++) {
                    String itemURL = null;
                    String itemTitle = null;
                    String itemDescription = null;
                    String itemGUID = null;
                    String itemPubDate = null;
                    String itemEnclosureURL = null;
                    String itemEnclosureMIMEType = null;

                    Node itemNode = allItemNodes.item(itemIndex);
                    NodeList tagNodes = itemNode.getChildNodes();
                    for(int tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < tagNodes.getLength(); tagIndex++){
                        Node tagNode = tagNodes.item(tagIndex);
                        String tag = tagNode.getNodeName();

                        if (XML_TAG_LINK.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                            itemURL = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        } else if (XML_TAG_TILE.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                            itemTitle = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        } else if (XML_TAG_DESCRIPTION.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                            itemDescription = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        } else if (XML_TAG_ENCLOSURE.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                            NamedNodeMap enclosureAttributes = tagNode.getAttributes();
                            itemEnclosureURL = enclosureAttributes.getNamedItem(XML_ATTRIBUTE_URL).getTextContent();
                            itemEnclosureMIMEType = enclosureAttributes.getNamedItem(XML_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE).getTextContent();
                        } else if (XML_TAG_PUB_DATE.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                            itemPubDate = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        } else if (XML_TAG_GUID.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                            itemGUID = tagNode.getTextContent();
                        }
                    }

                    responseItems.add(new ItemResponse(itemURL, itemTitle, itemDescription,
                            itemGUID, itemPubDate, itemEnclosureURL, itemEnclosureMIMEType));
                    responseFeeds.add(new FeedResponse(feedUrlString, channelTitle, channelURL, channelDescription, responseItems));
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                setErrorCode(ERROR_IO);
                return null;

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                setErrorCode(ERROR_PARSING);
                return null;
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                setErrorCode(ERROR_PARSING);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return responseFeeds;

    }

    private String optFirstTagDocument(Document document, String tagName) {
        NodeList elementsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if (elementsByTagName.getLength() > 0){
            return elementsByTagName.item(0).getTextContent();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static class FeedResponse {
        public final String channelFeedURL;
        public final String channelTitle;
        public final String channelURL;
        public final String channelDescription;
        public final List<ItemResponse> channelItems;

        FeedResponse(String channelFeedURL, String channelTitle, String channelURL, String channelDescription, List<ItemResponse> channelItems) {
            this.channelFeedURL = channelFeedURL;
            this.channelTitle = channelTitle;
            this.channelURL = channelURL;
            this.channelDescription = channelDescription;
            this.channelItems = channelItems;
        }

    }

    public static class ItemResponse {
        public final String itemURL;
        public final String itemTitle;
        public final String itemDescription;
        public final String itemGUID;
        public final String itemPubDate;
        public final String itemEnclosureURL;
        public final String itemEnclosureMIMEType;

        ItemResponse(String itemURL, String itemTitle, String itemDescription, String itemGUID,
                     String itemPubDate, String itemEnclosureURL, String itemEnclosureMIMEType) {
            this.itemURL = itemURL;
            this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
            this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
            this.itemGUID = itemGUID;
            this.itemPubDate = itemPubDate;
            this.itemEnclosureURL = itemEnclosureURL;
            this.itemEnclosureMIMEType = itemEnclosureMIMEType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe change them to Protected? protected static final String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop over the FeedResponse List you can pull out their fields and then loop over their FeedItem Lists to get the items and build up the RssFeed and RssItems within them as you go:

```
GetFeedsNetworkRequest request = new GetFeedsNetworkRequest(feedURLs);
List<FeedResponse> feedResponses = request.performRequest();
for (FeedResponse feedResponse : feedReponses) {
    // gather fields you need to construct RssFeed
    String channelTitle = feedResponse.channelTitle;
    List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemResponse itemResponse : feedResponse.channelItems) {
        // gather fields you need to construct RssItem
        String itemDescription = itemResponse.itemDescription;
        items.add(new RssItem(..., itemDescription, ...));
    }
    feeds.add(new RssFeed(..., channelTitle, ..., items, ...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `List<FeedResponse> feedResponse` and `String channelTitle = feedResponse.channelTitle` were the pieces I was drawing a blank on.

Comment: My pleasure.  I'm glad I was able to help.